# how to use external APIs in extension manifest v3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, sandbox, content-security-policy

I am creating twitter extension and I am using some external APIs.
I used manifest v2 before and I am going to upgrade to manifest v3.
The problem is about content_security_policy. I was using a lot of external APIs.
it is manifest v2 file.

```js
{
  "short_name": "Twitter PAY Extension",
  "name": "Twitter PAY Extension",
  "version": "1.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
     "scripts": ["app/const.js","app/jquery.js","app/inject.js","app/bg.js"]
  },
   "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": {
    "128": "ext.png",
    "16": "ext.png",
    "48": "ext.png"
  },
  "default_title": "Twitter EXT"
},
"description": "Twitter EXT",
"icons": {
 "128": "ext.png",
 "16": "ext.png",
 "48": "ext.png"
},
  "content_scripts" : [
    {
      "matches": [ "https://twitter.com/*" ],
      "css": ["/css/root.css","/static/css/content.css","/css/modal.css"],
      "js": ["/static/js/content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "web_accessible_resources":[
    "/static/css/content.css", "/static/media/*","/app/*"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://unpkg.com https://api.devnet.solana.com https://aframe.io https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ https://solarity.muhash.com/api/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" 
}
```

how can I use external APIS in manifest v3?